# How to update a copied list without updating the original one in python

Tags: python, list, pycharm

I want to update a copied list but when I do that it updates both the original and copied one

```
b=[1,2,3]
a=b
a[0]=2
print(a)
print(b)
```

but the value of b changed and became [2,2,3]

Comment: To perform a copy use `a=b[:]`

Comment: `a=b` is **not** a copy.

Comment: `a = b.copy()` in this case but if you have nested lists use `import copy; a = copy.deepcopy(b)`

Comment: thank u that's a suitable answer